# how to open encrypted files

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-word, encryption, virus

i got a virus,`CryptoLocker`, few weeks ago, and i managed to eliminate it, but all files on my pc are now 
encrypted, and they have got this extension, for example

***nameFile.docx.imivxjj***

when i try to remove the `imivxjj` i'm able to open it with Word, but at the same time, Word say to me that it's corrupted.

is there any way to open it,it's a very important file for me, and i've no others copy.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your files are encrypted.  By just removing the malware you have not removed your ONLY way of decrypting the files.  You need to restore your files from an offline backup.  Your encrypted files cannot be decrypted without the key which is cannot be retrieved since you removed the malware.

Comment: @Ramhound Happily not true; the encryption servers were captured by the authorities and they made the decryption keys available to the public.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoLocker#Takedown_and_recovery_of_files

Comment: @KevinPanko - I am aware of that event.  They don't have all decryption keys though.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this site: https://decryptcryptolocker.com/

They've got a copy of the encryption key database as it was seized by the authorities... assuming your encryption key is in there it should get you back on track.

Comment: Of course that is an older copy of the database.  It doesn't include the keys from the new variants of cryptolocker.